# How to split Excel screen with Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been trying to use Openpyxl to split the Excel screen vertically (in Excel the Split button in the View tab on the ribbon). I haven't found any guide, how to do this. But I have found this web page (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.views.html) and I think the "ySplit" property may be the solution. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out how to use it properly. I've tried the following code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sh = wb.active
sh.sheet_view.pane.ySplit = 20
```

> EDIT: But this code does not work: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'ySplit'.

I've also tried some variations of the code above (with ySplit). But without success. If anybody could help me to find a way, how to split the screen, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

> EDIT2: The solution was provided by stovfl in comments. The code
>   should be:

```
sh.sheet_view.pane = openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane(xSplit=20.0, ySplit=None, topLeftCell='C1', activePane='topLeft', state='split')
```

Comment: It's not what you wanted exactly, but, sh.freeze_panes="D4" works, to do 'View' 'Freeze Panes'. I can't find a solution to make split panes work in openpyxl

Comment: @Samantha Thank you for the suggestion. I know about freezing panes, but unfortunately that is not very useful in this case.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you. I tried your suggestion and the output is "None". Not sure why. The result is the same, when I use the files I need to process or when I try it with a completely new Excel file.

Comment: @stovfl Perfect! That's it. Only vertical splitting is done with xSplit and not ySplit. But that is detail. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question** How to split Excel screen with Openpyxl?

To define, to show a Worksheet splitted, you have to create a `openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane` object and assign it to `myWorksheet.sheet_view.pane`.

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.views import Pane

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

ws.sheet_view.pane = Pane(xSplit=20.0, ySplit=None, 
                          topLeftCell='C1', activePane='topLeft', state='split')

wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

> [openPyXL - worksheet.views.Pane](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.views.html#openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane)
>
> ```
> class openpyxl.worksheet.views.Pane(xSplit=None, ySplit=None, 
>                                     topLeftCell=None, 
>                                     activePane='topLeft', state='split')[source]
> ```
>
> > **activePane**
> >             Value must be one of `{‘topLeft’, ‘bottomRight’, ‘topRight’, ‘bottomLeft’}`
> >
> > **state**
> >           Value must be one of `{‘split’, ‘frozen’, ‘frozenSplit’}`
> >
> > **topLeftCell**
> >             Values must be of type `<class ‘str’>`
> >
> > **xSplit**
> >             Values must be of type `<class ‘float’>`
> >
> > **ySplit**
> >             Values must be of type `<class ‘float’>`