# Freeze Panes first two rows and column with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Trying to freeze the first two rows and first column with openpyxl, however, whenever doing such Excel says that the file is corrupted and there is no freeze.

Current code:

```py
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
worksheet = workbook[first_sheet]
freeze_panes = Pane(xSplit=2000, ySplit=3000, state="frozen", activePane="bottomRight")
worksheet.sheet_view.pane = freeze_panes
```

Took a look at the documentation, however, there is little explanation on parametere setting.

Desired output:
[image]

Came across this answer, however, it fits a specific use case, hence, wanted to make a general question for future reference:
[How to split Excel screen with Openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141377/how-to-split-excel-screen-with-openpyxl)

Comment: Can you edit that answer to suit your use case?

Comment: Did not ask for desired output.

Comment: @SolarMike "it fits a specific use case" the documentation on this aspect is poor, hence, cannot modify to match my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To freeze the first two rows and first column, use the sample code below... `ws.freeze_panes` works. Note that, like you would do in excel, select the cell above and left of which you want to freeze. So, in your case, the cell should be `B3`. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
ws=wb['Sheet1']
mycell = ws['B3']
ws.freeze_panes = mycell 
wb.save('Sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: That works like a charm! How about if I'd like to only freeze the first X rows or first X columns?

Comment: Change 4th line to `mycell = ws.cell(x+1, x+1)`

Comment: Where the first parameter is the row and second is column?

Comment: correct.... row, column

Answer (score 0):

```
# To freeze top rows 
ws.views.sheetView[0].topLeftCell = 'A1' # scroll to top left corner
ws.freeze_panes = 'F7' # freeze command
# To freeze rows from last save point of your workbook
ws.freeze_panes = 'F7' 

# To freeze columns 
ws.freeze_panes = 'G1' # This line freeze A to G columns
ws.freeze_panes = 'B1' # This line freeze A column.
```